# MovieClip not responding to a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have a complicated problem that I don't know where it comes from.
I have three movie clip in my first frame that each one call "homework" function.

**Problem**:
There is something wrong with the third one that if you click on it first it works correctly, but if you click on the other objects and then come back and try third one it doesn't work anymore.

I don't have this problem with the others `MovieClip` objects so how is this problem possible for third MC using the exact same function?

Here is the `homeWork` function:

```
function homeWork(a :int) :void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
    cubeContainer.addChild(movieClip);
    movieClip.x= 20;
    movieClip.y= 20;
    var j:int =0;

    for( var i = a; i < (a+10); i++)
    {
        cubeContainer.addChild(photos[i]);
        photos[i].width = 130;
        photos[i].height = 130;
        photos[i].x = j-80;
        photos[i].y = stage.height-photos[i].height;
        j += 90;
        photos[i].doubleClickEnabled=true;
        photos[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK ,covering);
        dragAndDrop(photos[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `trace( "doing homework function" );` as the first line before all other code in the **homeWork** function. This will confirm if the function **actually** runs when the third MC is clicked. Let us know. PS: Use option `Debug Movie` not `Test Movie` in the IDE if not seeing any error logs in the `Output` panel.

Comment: I tried this and it seems like i didnt click on the third MC!!! because nothing happened even when i trace sth just before calling my func

Comment: I cant explain whats happening i delete my button and insert another one now the new one work correctly but my second one go like the prev!!!

Comment: Just a guess: something with the instance names of the buttons? Like, they're the same.